# org.hibernate.HibernateException in a basic program of Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

i am using MySQL workbench 5.2 CE database with a basic hibernate program
at run time it give me error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

this code in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
          <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.212/da?autoReconnect=true&amp;useOldUTF8Behavior=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" /></property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">MyEclipse Derby</property>
        </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: This is unrelated but you have some extra garbage at the end of your `connection.url` string, remove them. It should be `<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.212/da?autoReconnect=true&amp;useOldUTF8Behavior=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>`

Answer (score 2):

Put the [mysql jdbc driver jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) on your classpath - if it is a web application that is `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: i have put this in class path:
Hibernate 3.3 Annotations & Entity Manager,
Hibernate 3.3 Core Libraries,
Hibernate 3.3 Advanced Support Libraries,
derbyclient.jar - Hibernate_example/lib

Comment: and I have linked to the driver donwload page, from where you can obtain the jdbc driver, and also put it on the classpath.